# When hovering one DOM element display another

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

With CSS/LESS, is it possible somehow to display (it's default is "display: none;") `sidebar-submenus`, when hovering `sidebar-category`?

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar-categories">
            <div id="menuDashboard" class="sidebar-category sidebar-category-top active">
                <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar-submenus">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this LESS:

```
body {
    &.sidebar-collapsed {
        #sidebar-submenus {
            display: none;
        }

        #sidebar-categories:hover {
            /*#Display sidebar-submenus with block somehow..? */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a typo in the question? You're basically asking if it's possible to display A when hovering A. :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
    #sidebar-categories:hover {
       + #sidebar-submenus { display:block; }
    }
```

Comment: I think i have some other rule overridding making the test hard, i will get back as soon as i can.

Comment: I doesn't work. Please provide a Fiddle if you can prove it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible because in CSS it's not possible to get a parent element.

Comment: In your code you have 'sidebar-menus' as the next sibling of 'sidebar-categories', and seem to be asking to display 'sidebar-menus' on hover of 'sidebar-categories'. In that case + works to find the very next sibling. You are correct that you can not specifically target a parent from a child element in CSS.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Information.3A_Selectors_based_on_relationships

Comment: You are right, it's works prefectly! Thanks alot. All though I can't reference any arbitrary DOM element, now thanks to you I know about the "+" and can add it to my toolbelt, and as you are stating, it's all I need to solve my issue.